# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci4\system\Common.php on line 45

Tags: xampp

I am trying to install codeigniter4 in xampp but i am getting the error like "
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci4\system\Common.php on line 45". What can i do?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1j4F.png)

Comment: Update your php version.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.